# After running "python manage.pr makemigrations" indjango, models are still left un migrated with this message on CLI

Tags: mysql, django, django-models

It is impossible to add a non-nullable field 'core' to event without specifying a default. This is because the database needs something to populate existing rows.
Please select a fix:

1. Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows with a null value for this column)
2. Quit and manually define a default value in models.py.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pw1zP.png)
[my models](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mwzzU.png)

Comment: 1. Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows with a null value for this column)
this means you added new field to table which is `null=false` so django is asking to what to do with old records. what will be the value of that new field for older records. so you have to set either `null=True` or `default=somevalue` for older records. and then `makemigrations` and `migrate`

Answer (score 0):

Do one thing, delete last two migration files and then try these commands:

```
python manage.py makemigrations appname

python manage.py sqlmigrate appname 0001 #This value will generate automatically after makemigrations. It can be any 0001, 0002 and so on.

python manage.py migrate
```